# Display image from JSON/API in React using JSX

Tags: json, image, reactjs, concatenation, jsx

I'm a React noob and I'm making an API request to retrieve JSON from a movie API and then displaying information about the movies, including the movie poster, in my component. I was able to retrieve and display text, but I am having trouble displaying images using JSX and the URL of the database.

I've assigned the images to post.poster_path and I'm attempting to concatenate the rest of the URL to the JSX.

```
<img src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/"+post.poster_path} alt="Movie Poster"/>
```

This doesn't work.

poster_path contains the image, I have verfied this in React tools. How do I properly concatenate the rest of the URL to post.poster_path?

Comment: Can you tell us what src ends up being when you inspect it? "This doesn't work" should be a more verbose description of what exactly happens.

Comment: The image doesn't display at all because I am assuming the concatenation is incorrect. The alt tag "Movie Poster" displays.

Comment: Yes, the image doesn't show, but can you inspect the element with chrome web tools (etc.) and tell us what ends up being the src? I haven't used react in a few months, so nothing looks wrong, but that's how I'd start.

Comment: Try using `require`: `<img src={require("image.jpg")} />`

Answer (score 2):

If

> post.poster_path = 'image.png'

and the whole url is

> https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/image.png"

for your image then the img tag will be as follows

```
<img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${post.poster_path}`} alt="Movie Poster"/>
```

In JSX if you have a value in variable and need to concat with a string you use tick `

```
eg. {`string ${variableName}`}
```

and if post.poster_path has the whole path then:

```
<img src={post.poster_path} alt="Movie Poster"/>
```