# Concatenate local path + dynamic images from Map - React.Js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, concatenation

i'm trying to do a CardList items from a local  `data.json` file using React.Js.

To load the data i'm using a map function:

```
const ItemsList = data.map(item=>{

  return(
  <li><img key={item.id} src={"assets/images/sampleImages/" + item.image}/></li>
  )
})
```

[Code - PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/mgJuavU4)

but i cannot get the image. No error, just a broken image icon appear.

I've try:

[This solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooKWzJ?editors=1010) And with URL works, but don't work with path.

[Also this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725373/display-image-from-json-api-in-react-using-jsx). And nothing works.

[image: Broken images to illustrate.]

Comment: Have you tried with "require"? It should be like this: src={require('./assets/images/sampleImages/${item.image}')}

Comment: Can you please post your JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly import the image like this (You can amend it accordingly)

```
import imageBaseURL = "./assets/images/sampleImages/";
```

Then inside your ItemList make use of [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this :

```
const ItemsList = data.map( item => {
  return(
  <li><img key={item.id} alt="TitleOfImage" src={`${imageBaseURL}${item.image}`}/></li>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First step:

Importing image and store it in one variable ( ExampleImg )

```
import ExampleImg from '../example.png';
```

Second step:

Inject the image as a src

```
<img src = { ExampleImg } />
```

Comment: i cannot store it in one variable because the path it's static and the name.jpg change according the image.  maybe 2 variables ?